# TemplateDoesNotExist at / template path

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to create the backend of a portfolio and I'm trying to use a template but it says it doesn't exist but shows the correct file path in the error message.
This is the urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                         document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                         document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def home(request):
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

And this is my templates setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS':  [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ....
        ],
    },
  },


]
```

The directory structure is:

[image: 1. my project - my project -init.py -settings.py -urls.py -manage.py -my app 2. templates 3. static]

Core is the app name

Comment: Please include ```urls.py``` and also the full traceback.

Comment: @Ram I have done that

Comment: change DIRS to  [] and try

Comment: @Sumithran it returns the same error

Comment: can you share the **full** error traceback

Comment: also restart the development server..

Comment: File "C:\Users\zaina\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Interactive-Resume-HNGi8\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\zaina\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Interactive-Resume-HNGi8\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\zaina\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Interactive-Resume-HNGi8\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response

Comment: if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Sorry, I split it because it was too long and I already restarted the dev server

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

change the home view to

```
def home(request):
    return render("home.html")
```

and sett DIRS to blank in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    ...
    'DIRS':  [],
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: I did this and the error changed to:
AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: which version of Django you are using? also, share your complete settings.py file.

Comment: This is the link to the settings file[link] ( https://github.com/Zeesky-code/Interactive-Resume-HNGi8/blob/main/resume/resume/settings.py)
And I'm using Django 3.2.6

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you try this in your settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'templates'
 
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and after that request you html in your views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

and in you urls.py

```
path('',views.home, name='home')
```

this better and much cleaner way to tell django where to look fot templates and tell me if you still geting error

Comment: @ZainabLawal add the traceback

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving the statics and template directories into the app directory.